# Can I get the uploaded filename without passing play.data.Upload directly?

Tags: java, image, playframework

I found two snippets that show how to do image upload in Play:

- [Include a Blob in your model](http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/4)
- [Use play.data.Upload](http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/16)

I kind of like the Blob approach, it's simpler and more elegant. What I'm asking is ... can I get the original filename with this approach? I noticed that [the Upload class](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/data/Upload.html) has a `getFileName()` method. Can I access the filename in the Blob approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your controller's method, you can use something like:

```
File f = params.get("image", File.class);
```

(where "image" is the name of your blob parameter) to get the File object.

Finally, you can get the filename with

```
f.getName();
```

(source: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/21ccf6057d8bf4f5?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the third approach: define controller's method parameter type of java.io.File. Then you get uploaded file name using file.getName()

Comment: Hmm. I think I remember seeing this once. Too bad that when I google "image upload play framework", I don't find a snippet with a File. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It does't quite do what I want, because I do want to keep Blobs in the model itself, and I didn't find an easy way to convert a File to a Blob. I'm sure there is ... but isn't this quite equivalent to just using play.data.Upload? This is what I ended up doing.